# How to ensure that a div is always centered when another one disappears after an animation?

Tags: css

*([CSB](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-sanne-oh5bbd?file=/src/App.js) for reference)*

I have a button comprised of an icon and some text. When the button is hovered, the text moves to the right, and so does the icon. It creates a nice animation

[image]

The problem is I make this transition happen with the following code:

```css
.button:not(.disabled):hover .icon {
  transform: translate3d(150%, 0, 0);
}
```

The `150%` is just an arbitrary value, if you go inside `App.js` and change the `width` of the icon (line 10), you can tell that it's no longer centered. I can't wrap my head around a solution that would ensure the following (my goals):

- When the button is not hovered, both the icon and the text should be center.
- When the button is hovered, only the icon should be *ultimately* centered.

Would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Perfectly-smooth solution that works for every situation:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
}

button {
  --gap: 5px;
  
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: .3em .7em;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  gap: var(--gap);
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}

button > div > i {
  flex: 0;
  transition: inherit;
}

button > div > span { 
  flex: 1;
  transition: inherit;
}

button:hover > div {
  width: calc(200% + var(--gap));
}

button:hover > div > i {
  flex: 1;
  color: crimson;
}

button:hover > div > span {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <div>
    <i>♥️</i>
    <span>Short</span>
  </div>
</button>

<button>
  <div>
    <i>♥️</i>
    <span>Normal label</span>
  </div>
</button>

<button>
  <div>
    <i>♥️</i>
    <span>Very long label text example</span>
  </div>
</button>
```

### [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/PoeGzmX?editors=1100)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, this won't do, but it *does answer my question.* Are you saying that it's not possible if the button doesn't have a fixed width? I will accept this as an answer since it answers my question, but is there no other way?

Comment: I've been breaking my head over this for hours, it's far from easy. CSS can be quite primitive in some scenarios. This is a very tough one. I have been thinking about this problem a lot. If I come up with a solution I will add it to my answer here.

Comment: @DanielIvory - I've suddenly had a genius idea and have edited my answer. This works perfect! :)

Answer (score 1):

First give your button a fixed width.

```
.button {
  width: 130px;
}
```

and then you just need to set the position of your icon class to absolute on button hover.

```
.button:not(.disabled):hover .icon {
  position: absolute;
}
```